# Can one use Gauss' law to calculate the gravitational field around an arbitrary (continuous) mass ditribution?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

Consider an arbitrary mass distribution. Can we use Gauss' law to calculate the gravitational field around the mass? Or can we apply Gauss' law only in cases where in Gauss' law we can take $\vec g$ out of the integral:

$$\int\int \vec g d\vec A =-4\pi GM$$

which, like I see it can only be done if the mass distribution is spherical and has a homogeneous density. Were this not the case then we had to know $\vec g$ for every point on the mass enclosing surface, so we didn't have to use Gauss' law in the first place.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/326163/2451

Answer (score 2):

Using the Gauss' law you can only calculate the total gravitational flux through any closed surface. After that, you will have to necessarily use some symmetry arguments (choose a convenient shape for your surface, argue that the flux passing through this particular part of the surface is zero due to symmetry, etc.) to deduce the field.

But that does not mean your mass distribution has to be spherical. It could be, say, an infinitely extending sheet of mass or an infinitely long cylinder of mass. In both cases, you will observe there is some inherent symmetry. The mass distribution is not required to be homogeneous either, only that it must satisfy the symmetry requirements.

Comment: So it's the symmetry that's the most important to calculate the gravitational field from Gauss' law?

Comment: Yes. Symmetry is needed to get from the flux that the Gauss' law provides to the value of the field.

Comment: Symmetry is important in an exact calculation. A general problem could be integrated numerically.  So without symmetry Gauss' law holds, but one is forced to use numerical methods if there is no symmetry to the mass distribution.

Answer (score 2):

It is always true that $\oint_S \vec g\cdot d\vec S=-4\pi GM_{encl}$, where
$M_{encl}$ is the mass enclosed by the surface $S$, but it is not always useful.

If you want the field at some point $\vec r$, and $\vec r$ is on a surface for which $\vec g\cdot d\vec S=\vert \vec g\vert dS\cos\theta$ is constant with:

1. $\vert\vec g\vert$ constant everywhere on the surface,
2. $\cos\theta$ constant everywhere on the surface,

then
\begin{align}
\oint_S \vec g\cdot d\vec S&=\oint_S \vert \vec g\vert dS\cos\theta
=  \vert \vec g\vert \cos\theta\oint_S dS\, ,\\
&= \vert \vec g\vert \cos\theta\, S 
\end{align}
and you can then invert to get
$$
\vert\vec g\vert=\frac{-4\pi G M_{encl}}{A\cos\theta}\, .
$$
with $A=\oint_S dS$.

In practice, finding a surface for which the above conditions are met can be done when the mass distribution has some symmetry: for spherical mass distribution the surface would be a sphere, for cylindrical mass distributions a cylinder etc.  In these simple geometrical cases $\cos\theta=1$ usually.  In such cases, the *direction* of $\vec g$ is also obtained by symmetry.

The $M_{encl}$ is then evaluated by integrating the density of matter over the volume enclosed by the surface $S$. The density need not be homogenous but it will have some symmetry that has pre-fed into the choice of surface.  In the case of spherically symmetric mass distribution, for instance, $\rho=\rho(r)$ and the mass enclosed would be
$$
M_{encl}=4\pi \int_{r_0}^r  r^2\rho(r)dr
$$
for a mass distribution extending from some small radius $r_0$ to the point $r$, and $\rho(r)$ can be pretty much any function of $r$ alone.  In such a case the surface would a sphere of radius $r$ so $A=4\pi r^2$, the direction of $\vec g$ is $\hat r$ and is colinear with $d\vec S$ so that $\cos\theta=1$, and we  have
$$
\vec g= -\frac{4\pi GM_{encl}}{4\pi r^2}\,\hat r\, .
$$
If the surface encloses all the body generating the field, then $M_{encl}=M$ and we recover the usual expression
$$
\vec g=-\frac{GM}{r^2}\hat r\, .
$$